# SUM OF numbers higher then 0

Tags: php

Im doing homework and i have tried doing this code but it seems that is not good, my homework is to get sum of numbers that are higher than 0.

```
<?PHP
$b=array (1,2,-3,0,7,25,0,42,1,-10);
$s=0; $BUB=0; 
for($BUB=0;$BUB=10;$BUB++)
{
    if($b>0){
        $s=$s+$b;} [$bub=0];
        $BUB++;

}
echo "suma je $s" ;

?>
```

Comment: No need to worry.Nothing happed if you add 0 to the value . 120 + 0 = 120 always

Comment: it is something like counter

Comment: but the code is not working

Comment: @samitha correct, but numbers less than 0? 120 + 0 + -13 != 120

Comment: your code is all over the place... Try running your code on paper and see what a mess it is... then try to fix it (which in this case I mean rewrite the whole thing)

Answer (score 1):

```
$b=array (1,2,-3,0,7,25,0,42,1,-10);

$r = array_sum(
    array_filter(
        $b,
        function ($value) {
            return $value > 0;
        }
    )
);
var_dump($r);
```

or

```
$b=array (1,2,-3,0,7,25,0,42,1,-10);

$r = array_reduce(
    $b,
    function($adder, $value) {
        return $adder += ($value > 0) ? $value : 0;
    }
);
var_dump($r);
```

Comment: Remark: If you use this (really nice) solution, I want to admit that  Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.0. So running an older PHP Version would force you to declare the function and refrence it with it's name instead of using inline code :)

Comment: Of course @serjoscha but nobody should be running anything less that PHP 5.3 these days, and only die-hard old-style code-fans should be running anything less than 5.4 :)

Comment: I agree with that. Just wanted to mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach(array (1,2,-3,0,7,25,0,42,1,-10) as $num) {
  if($num > 0) {
    $sum += $num;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's nice that you're doing his homework for him without him learning anything. Really, it is.

Comment: He asked for it?! Why shall we denie an question?!

Comment: "he asked for condoms, even though he's only 12"

Comment: @serjoscha The guy mentioned it was homework (so he's obviously a beginner), from his code itself it's clear that he has quite a few misunderstandings. Giving a working answer with zero explanation will likely result in him taking it, using it, regardless of him understanding it. The best outcome is that his teacher will ask him how it works, he won't be able to answer and will be forced to learn how it works. The worst outcome is he gets further up the "qualified" ladder without really knowing what he's doing. If the latter keeps happening, would you give him a job?

Comment: Well I would explain my answer, for usual I indeed do. But this code takes advantage of absolute basic language constructs. Nothing complex about it. What could I explain about that code snipet? The "greater operator"? Or the "+=" operator?

Comment: You could explain the differences between his/yours, where he went wrong, what/why it isn't necessary, why you chose a foreach over a for. Remembering what coding was like at the beginner stage, your answer probably looks like a god wrote it! And considering he went for `$s=$s+$b;` instead of `$s += $b` it looks like your usage of `+=` is an unknown thing! Ofc that's just me complaining, time is scarce and I'm sure he appreciates the answer.